# ActiveAdmin dynamic select_tag based on other selections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Currently I have a form that looks like:

```
form_tag(manage_titans_admin_collection_path(collection), method: :post) do
  label_tag('Race:') +
  ' ' +
  select_tag(:race, options_for_select(Collectible.where(primary_type: 'cpt_golem').order('race asc').uniq.pluck(:race))) +
  ' ' +
  label_tag('Stage:') +
  ' ' +
  select_tag(:stage, options_for_select(1.upto(4))) +
  ' ' +
  label_tag('Level:') +
  ' ' +
  text_field_tag(:level, 1, style: 'width: 100px') +
  ' ' +
  submit_tag('Submit')
end
```

I want to change it such that the `:level` selection is a `select_tag` of consecutive numbers, which change according to the `:stage` selected. For example, if stage is 1, I want to show the levels 1-20, but if stage 2 is selected, I want to show levels 20 to 40.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

In the end the helper tags you are using translate to html so I would use a javascript function with jquery:
Assuming that you will have in your page a:

```
<select name="stage" id="stage">
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
```

And a:

```
<select name="level" id="level"></select>
```

The function would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#stage').on('change', function() {
        var level = $("#level");
        var value = this.value;
        level.empty();
        if (value == 1) {
            init = 1;
            final = 20;
        } else if(value == 2) {
            init = 21;
            final = 40;
        } else if(value == 3) {
            init = 41;
            final = 60;
        } else if (value == 4) {
            init = 61;
            final = 80;
        }
        var cont = 0;
        for(var i=0; (init+cont)<=final; i++) {
            level.append('<option value="'+(init + cont)+'">'+(init + cont)+'</option>')
            cont++;
        }
    });
    $('#stage').change();
});
```

If you want to change the levels just update the numbers in the function. Or add another condition.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I wrote up your methodology and made the implementation a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Same concept as @danielR but a little cleaner implementation:

(Also assumed as @danielR did that stage 2 range should be 21-40 not 20-40.)

**HTML**

```
<select id='stage'>
    <option></option>
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
    <option value='3'>3</option>
    <option value='4'>4</option>
</select>
<select id='level'><option></option></select>
```

**jQuery**

```
function addOptions(selector, modifier){
    $(selector).each(function(){ 
        $(this).find('option').remove().end().append('<option></option>');
        start = ((modifier - 1) * 20) + 1;
        end = modifier * 20;
        for (i = start; i <= end; i++){
            $('<option>').text(i).val(i).appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
}


$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#stage').on('change',function(){
        addOptions('#level', parseInt($(this).val(),10));
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/344ywxs0/6/)